How to encrypt the password in Snowflake
I have an SQL function to encrypt the password which is calling a External Name (Custom code) inside the function, Now I have to convert below code in Snowflake but could not find yet proper solution for this. Your suggestion would be appreciated.
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlString Encrypt(SqlString stringToEncrypt)
{
    SqlString result="";
    byte[] Iv_64 = { 55, 103, 246, 79, 36, 99, 167, 3 };
    byte[] Key_64 = { 42, 16, 93, 156, 78, 4, 218, 32 };

    if (stringToEncrypt != "")
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider CryptoProvidor = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, 
        CryptoProvidor.CreateEncryptor(Key_64, Iv_64), 
        CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs);
        sw.Write(stringToEncrypt);
        sw.Flush();
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        ms.Flush();
        result = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, 
        Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length));
    }

    return result;
}


Not related to the (general) ISO/ANSI SQL language, so I removed the  tag.

Hi - please update your question with the code you’ve managed to write so far and explain what exactly you are stuck with

In Snowflake you would likely replace your .Net function with the Snowflake function ENCRYPT_RAW or ENCRYPT.
